# (i) $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |\;xy = 1\}\,\bigcup\, \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |\;y = 0\}$ is not connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I need to understand the following

(i) $\{(x,y) \in R^2 |\;xy = 1\}\;U \{(x,y) \in R^2 |\;y = 0\}$ is not connected however

(ii) $ Y = \{(x,y) \in R^2 |\;x^2 + y^2 < 1\}\;U \{(x,y) \in R^2 |\;y = 1\}$ is path connected.

I attempt (i) along this line. For any $A = (a,0)$, I can find a ball of radius $1/2a$ such that $(a,1/a)$ lies outside this ball. Suppose $\exists (c,1/c) \in B(1/2a,A)$, clearly $(c-a)^2 + 1/c^2 \leq 1/4a^2.$ If I can contradict this, I am done.

Noting that $a<c<a+1/2a$, $(c-a)^2 + 1/c^2 > 1/c^2 > 1/(a^2+1+1/4a^2)$. Now it suffices to show that $1/(a^2+1+1/4a^2) < 1/4a^2$, which is equivalent to showing $3a^2 > 1+ 1/4a^2$ which is true clearly $\forall$ a>1.

And here is my idea for path connectedness of (ii). To get a path from $(a,b)$ (interior of the circle) and $(c,d)$ (on the tangent), define $f:[0,1] \to Y$ to be $f(t) := t(a,b)+(1-t)(c,d).$ This is continuous and lies completely in Y as every point f(x) in Y except f(1) lies in the interior of the circle and f(1) lies in the tangent.

Are there any approaches for this that are more straight forward than this, say using some standard known results?

Answer (score 2):

Write $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |\;xy = 1\}\,\bigcup\, \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |\;y = 0\}$ as the union of three sets $A_1 = \{(x,y): x > 0, y > 0, xy = 1\}$, $A_2 = \{(x,y): x < 0, y < 0, xy = 1\}$ and $A_3 = \{(x,y): y = 0 \}$.

All three sets are closed in the plane, as $p: (x,y) \rightarrow xy$ is continuous and $A_1 = p^{-1}[\{1\}] \cap ([0,\infty) \times [0,\infty))$, $A_2 = p^{-1}[\{1\}] \cap (-\infty,0] \times (-\infty,0])$ and $A_3 = \pi_2^{-1}[\{0\}]$ where $\pi_2(x,y) = y$ is of course continuous. So all three sets are closed and disjoint (and non-empty) in $A$, their union is $A$, so all are open in $A$ as well. So we have a decomposition of $A$ and so $A$ is disconnected.

For the second, just show there is a path $p_1$ from any point $(x,y)$ in the open unit circle to $(0,1)$ that stays entirely inside the circle except for the final point. This is just convexity (as you suggest). Then there is a straight line path from any point in $\{(x,y): y = 1\}$ to $(0,1)$ as well. And if a space is such that there is a central point to which all of the points have a path, then the space is path-connected on general principles.

Answer (score 0):

[For i)]

By intuition/visually, we would expect this set to have 3 connected components. Showing disconnectedness can be done by writing a set as a disjoint union of two open sets, so let's try do this by fitting $\{(x,y):xy=1,x>0,y>0\}$ inside one open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and fitting $\{(x,y):x>0,y>0\}\cup\{(x,y):x=0\}$ inside another open set.

Indeed, the first set lies inside $\{xy>0\}\cap\{x>0\}$, which is clearly open, and the second lies within $\{y<\frac{1}{1+\vert x\vert}\}\}$, which as the preimage of an open set is thus also open.

It thus follows that the given set can be decomposed into two disjoint, relatively open sets, and hence is disconnected.

[For ii)]

Everything in the first set is path-connected to the origin, everything in the second set is path connected to $(0,1)$, and the origin is path-connected to $(0,1)$ by the vertical line straight up.

Comment: Questions reagarding (i) 1. "the second lies within $\{y<1/1+|x|\}$, which as the preimage of an open set is thus also open." Which map do you mean? 2. Also, don't we need the two open sets to be disjoint? The interior of first quadrant and the area below graph 1/(1+|x|) are not disjoint, however!!

Comment: One more....fitting $\{(x,y):x>0,y>0\}∪\{(x,y):x=0\}$ inside another open set. This is interior of first quadrant plus Y axis. Did you have same thing in mind?

Comment: Your comment about them not being disjoint is right - thanks. I think the proof can still be fixed though. Will amend when I get home.

Comment: On thinking a bit more, actually you are right. Let our set in (i) be $X \subset R^2$. The open sets you provided in $R^2$ are open in the subspace topology of $X$ and automatically becomes disjoint in $X$. Thus, there exists two non-empty disjoint open sets in X whose union is X.

Answer (score 0):

I think your aproach on (i) is a bit unclear. Remember what you wan't to show is that you can find two disjoint open sets that covers the set. The obvious choice is to cut the real plane along the curve $y = 1/(2x)$. Basically the set's $A = \{(x,y) | y > 1/(2x)\}$ and $B = \{(x,y) | y < 1/(2x)\}$ are open and disjoint and the only points that isn't in either of them are those for which $y = 1/(2x)$, but none of those points are in the set of interest.

Your approach on (ii) seems to be hurried as you seem to forget that you can't have a straight line between these points (also of course you would need to be able to connect arbitrary points no matter which part they're in). However what we have here is a starshaped region, that is that you can draw a straight line from any point in it to a select point $(0,1)$, to construct a path between two points you just take a straight line from the first point to $(0,1)$ and then a straight line from $(1,0)$ to the other point.

Answer (score 0):

If two subsets $C_1, C_2\subset X$ in a topological space are closed and disjoint then their union is a disconnected space by definition.

In your case $C_1$ is the hyperbola and $C_2$ is the $x$-axis which are disjoint and individually closed subspaces in the plane.